# Match single word, with possible punctuation or pluralization at end (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been getting better at Regex, but I've come up with something that is beyond what I'm currently able to do.

I want to build a function to test (return true or false) to test to see if a word is found inside a string.  But I wouldn't want to have a positive match if the word was found inside of another word.  I would also like to build in the possibility of checking for pluralization.

Here are some examples of the results I'd expect to get:

**Word to look for:** "bar"

**"Strings to search in" //what it should return as**

"foo bar" //true

"foo bar." //true

"foo bar!" //true (would be true with any other punctuation before or after 'bar' too)

"foo bars." //true

"foo bares." //true (even though bares has a different meaning then bars, I would be okay with this returning true since I would need to check for words that pluralize with "es" and I wouldn't expect to build a regex to know which words pluralize with "s" and which to "es")

"my name is bart simpson" //false (bar is actually part of "bart")

"bart simpson went to the bar." //true

I'll be using javascript/jquery to check for matches

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: So "child" is not expected to match "children", correct?

Comment: Yes, I would not expect "child" to match "children".

Comment: Pluralization is not easy to do with regular expressions. What about _mouse/mice_ and _colossus/colossi_?

Comment: Frits, I would not expect to match these types of pluralization words.

Comment: How about these cases: `in5bar`, `bares_random`, `Ăbar`

Comment: I would expect `in5bar` and `Ăbar` to return false.  I would expect `bares_random` to be true (since it's 'bar'+'pluralization option'+'punctuation'+'other stuff')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var rgx = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '(?:es|s)?\\b');
rgx.test(string);
```

This will return `true` for all of the strings you specified in your request.  `\b` represents a "word boundary," which I believe is any character in `\W` (including period and exclamation point) as well as the start or end of the string.

Comment: This works great!  Just had to make one change to get it to work.  Changed "Regex" to "RegExp".  Thanks so much EP!

Comment: @StevenJenkins oops, I was using `RegExp` in all of my tests, but I wrote `Regex` in the answer first.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered and accepted, but I thought I'd provide a *slightly* over-engineered approach that does a better job of matching plural forms. Other than that, it uses exactly the same logic as @ExplosionPills' solution:

```
(function() {
  var isWord = function(word) { return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(word); },

      exceptions = {
        man:   'men',
        woman: 'women',
        child: 'children',
        mouse: 'mice',
        tooth: 'teeth',
        goose: 'geese',
        foot:  'feet',
        ox:    'oxen'
      },

      pluralise = function(word) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        if (word in exceptions) {
          // Exceptions
          return '(?:' + word + '|' + exceptions[word] + ')';

        } else if (word.match(/(?:x|s|[cs]h)$/)) {
          // Sibilants
          return word + '(?:es)?';

        } else if (word.match(/[^f]f$/)) {
          // Non-Geminate Labio-Dental Fricative (-f > -ves / -fs)
          return '(?:' + word + 's?|' + word.replace(/f$/, 'ves') + ')';

        } else if (word.match(/[^aeiou]y$/)) {
          // Close-Front Unround Pure Vowel (-Cy > -Cies)
          return '(?:' + word + '|' + word.replace(/y$/, 'ies') + ')';

        } else if (word.substr(-1) == 'o') {
          // Mid-Back Round Vowel (-o > -oes / -os)
          return word + '(?:e?s)?';

        } else {
          // Otherwise
          return word + 's?';
        }
      };

  String.prototype.containsNoun = function(singularNoun) {
    if (!isWord(singularNoun)) throw new TypeError('Invalid word');
    var check = new RegExp('\\b' + pluralise(singularNoun) + '\\b', 'gi');
    return check.test(this);
  };

  String.prototype.pluralException = function(plural) {
    if (!isWord(this) || !isWord(plural)) throw new TypeError('Invalid exception');

    var singular = this.toLowerCase();
    plural = plural.toLowerCase();

    if (!(singular in exceptions)) {
      exceptions[singular] = plural;
    }
  };
})();
```

It extends the native `String` object, so you use it like so:

```
'Are there some foos in here?'.containsNoun('foo'); // True
```

See [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Xophmeister/4952329) for some quick-and-dirty unit testing done in Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

```
/ (bar((e)?s)?)[ !?.]/
```

depending on what you need exactly this might work.
it won't find two bars in the string "bars bars" because of the overlapping spaces.

```
/ (bar((e)?s)?)(?=[ !?.])/
```

that should work with "bars bars" (two matches) since js1.5 which is supported by all the browsers anyway nowadays.